# Django : How to create a form that asks for phone number with a drop down country field?

Tags: python, django, forms

I have been learning Django for a week now.

I want to create a contact form that asks for phone number country code.

The form will ask for the phone number in two fields:
 1. user needs to select a dropdown fields of country code 
 2. user will enter the rest of the phone number

(see image below)

What is a simple way to do this in Django? With examples would be great.

[Mockup of the intended form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGcHM.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the following code to create the required form:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=32)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=32)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    country = forms.ChoiceField( choices=( ('1','USA (+1)'),
                            ('some other country','some other country'),
                            ...
                            ...
                        )
                )
    phone_number = forms.CharField(max_length=32)
```

Now you can use this form and format is as per you like in your HTML and save it as per your data models.